# Call another process's method in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, tornado

My setting is the following - I have a Tornado based HTTP server which is pretty much the "hello world" example:

```
server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
server.bind(8888)
server.start(2)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Now in this setting, I also have another process (let's call it control process) spawned by the root process. Thus this control process is a sibling to the two Tornado handler processes. Naturally I can communicate between the handler processes and the control process through a pipe created by the root process. I however, am more interested in calling a method of the control process and getting it's output.

What is the best approach to do such a thing? If I use the pipe for sending the request from a handler to the control and return the result, should I use a lock to implement process-safety?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a lock with pipes. The pipe is its own synchronization. Or, put a different way, the two sides of the pipe are separate objects.

(Of course the control process may need a lock internally, e.g., if it's handling the pipe from a different thread than the main event loop and needs to share any data with code that runs in the main loop, but that's not related to inter-process safety.)

Anyway, if you step back and think about this from a higher level, what you're implementing is the exact definition of an RPC mechanism. If what you're doing is simple enough, implementing it from scratch this way is fine, but if not, you may want to have add another protocol to `control` and let Tornado manage it along with your existing protocol(s).

Comment: Yes, it is exactly an RPC. And yes, I somehow got confused, that two inputs from the two handlers and their outputs may get mixed up somehow (shame on me). As I'm quite new with Tornado, could you specify what you meant by "adding another protocol to `control`"?

Comment: @DJV: I meant… whatever you meant by it the four times you used that name in your question. You want some "handler process" to make requests against "the control process". So, if that "control process" is already using Tornado to implement, e.g., a web app server, or a JSON-RPC-over-sockets server, or whatever, just add another protocol for the other process to use, instead of implementing something independent from scratch.